# Why [,,].join(' ') length is one less than array length?

Tags: javascript

What is the reason behind the length of `string` produced by joining `var arr = [,,]`, like so: `var str = arr.join(' ')` being one less than length of `arr`.

```js
var literal_arr = [,,],
    joined_literal_arr = literal_arr.join(' '),
    constructor_arr = new Array(2),
    joined_constructor_arr = new Array(2).join(' ');

console.log("Literal array notation length = ", literal_arr.length);

console.log("Joined literal array notation string length = ", joined_literal_arr.length);

console.log("Constructor array notation length = ", constructor_arr.length);

console.log("Joined constructor notation string length = ", joined_constructor_arr.length);
```

Comment: To be clear: You're asking about what `join` does with arrays of `length = 2` that have no entries in them, **not** about why `[,,]` produces an array with `length = 2` instead of `length = 3`, right? (At least two people have read it the other way, but to me your question is clearly about `join`, not array literal syntax.)

Comment: Yes! Precisely, my question is *what join does with arrays of length = 2 that have no entries in them?*. But I interpret *why [,,] produces an array with length = 2 instead of length = 3* as being an instance of my question.

Comment: I don't understand the second half of that comment. If your question is about join, it isn't about `[,,]`. (If you're wondering about `[,,]` being `length = 2`, though, it's because the final `,` is a *trailing comma* and is ignored: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas#Arrays)

Comment: It is not about join at all. The result of using join on arrays that have no entries in them instead.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am sorry sir, I didn't quite get your first comment at first. Now, I understand the part  *not about why [,,] produces an array with length = 2 instead of length = 3, right?* of that comment. Yes, it is not about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join#Description) :

> If an element is **undefined** or null, it is converted to the **empty string**.

In your case, you are creating an array with a particular length without any value(it would be `undefined`). So while joining there will be `length - 1` separators(since `undefined` already treated as an empty string) means `length - 1` spaces(`' '`).

Comment: *"In your case, you are creating an array with a particular length without any value(it would be null)."* No, the result of reading a gap in an array is `undefined`, not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple as `.join` will join array elements with `separator` provided as argument. It won’t append `separator` after the last element or prepend it before the first element. It will place `separator` between elements only.